# Error You called write() but provided no data to be written - on shopware plugin activation

Tags: plugins, shopware

i get the error

**Error You called write() but provided no data to be written**

when i will activate an plugin on shopware, anybody has the same problem and  have an tip for me?

Comment: Can you provide full error text?
What plugin you want to install?

Answer (score 1):

This error message is thrown in the snippet manager and means that the plugin, you are trying to install, is trying do load a snippet-file (like main.ini) which has no data in it. You could either remove the file or fill it with snippets.